# How do I use two domains with my VPS?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, vps

I'm planning on getting a VPS account and I'm wondering, if I get 2 domain names, how do I configure my VPS account to accomodate them? I'm planning on using Apache as my webserver. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all your DNS entries for different domains will point to the same ip address - ip of your vps; your apache will serve different content based on the host name that is requested.

this feature is called vhosts. you can find basic description of the idea on [apache project help page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html). and some tutorials: [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412) or [there](http://www.google.com/search?q=apache2+vhost+tutorial).

Comment: Yup, just configure the ServerNames in the vhost directive to the appropriate domain names and you're set.